# How to switch the position of two numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel column with the following entries

```
POINT (174.7753931 -36.8867484)
POINT (174.7749403 -36.89297140000001)
POINT (174.7604037 -36.8692689)
```

which is converted to

```
POINT (-36.8867484 174.7753931)
POINT (-36.89297140000001 174.7749403)
POINT (-36.8692689 174.7604037)
```

by

```
="POINT ("&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),99),")"," ")&LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-2),"POINT (","")&")"
```

How would I do the opposite? So,

```
POINT (-36.8867484 174.7753931)
POINT (-36.89297140000001 174.7749403)
POINT (-36.8692689 174.7604037)
```

becomes

```
POINT (174.7753931 -36.8867484)
POINT (174.7749403 -36.89297140000001)
POINT (174.7604037 -36.8692689)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Analyse what the formula is doing.  Your original one looks for the minus signs as a delimiter, in your second case a space is a delimiter between your numbers.  Change it to look for the space instead of the minus sign, making you sure to skip the first space after the word "POINT":

```
="POINT ("&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2,7)+1,99),")"," ")&LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,7)-2),"POINT (","")&")"
```